# PHP: How to add newline characters when writing to a file?

Tags: php, string, escaping

I'm creating a text string from a data-set and get the delimiter character for end of the line as an XML attribute. When I write the string to file delimiter appear as text. If I directly append it to the string it get interpreted as escape character correctly. How can append the XML attribute value to be interpreted as escape sequence? See the output below.

Appended from XML attribute:

```
$DefXML = simplexml_load_file($defFileName);
$escape = $DefXML['delimeter'];

$dataRecord .= $escape;
fwrite($outputFile, $dataRecord);
```

==>
HHHHHHHHHH 2015-02-22\r\n (This is wrong)

Append as string:

`$dataRecord .= "\r\n";`

```
fwrite($outputFile, $dataRecord);
```

==>
HHHHHHHHHH 2015-02-22 (Correct format)

Binary Output of this:

```
#od -c ACCOUNTS.txt
0000000   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H   H       2   0   1   5   -
0000020   0   2   -   2   2  \r  \n
```

Here is the XML I used to get the end of line character.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FILE name="ACCOUNTS.txt" delimeter="\r\n">
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also on Windows `\r\n` is the correct sequence, not `\n\r`.

Comment: Can you show the actual code that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: People need more information if you want them to help